# Create multiple subfolders in specific subfolders in Python

Tags: python, operating-system

If I have a folder `test` which has multiple subfolders `A`, `B`, `C`, etc., each has same structure `sub1`, `sub2` and `sub3`:

```
├─A
│  ├─sub1
│  ├─sub2
│  └─sub3
├─B
│  ├─sub1
│  ├─sub2
│  └─sub3
└─C
|   ├─sub1
|   ├─sub2
|   └─sub3
...
```

I want to create subfolders named `a` and `b` only in `sub1` and `sub2` and ignore other subfolders (`sub3...`). This is expected result:

```
├─A
│  ├─sub1|--a
│  |     |--b
│  ├─sub2|--a
│  |     |--b
│  └─sub3
├─B
│  ├─sub1|--a
│  |     |--b
│  ├─sub2|--a
│  |     |--b
│  └─sub3
└─C
│  ├─sub1|--a
│  |     |--b
│  ├─sub2|--a
│  |     |--b
   └─sub3
...
```

I can create folders `a` and `b` with code below, but I don't how can I do this `sub1` and `sub2`? Thanks.

```
import os

root_path =r"D:\test"
sub_folders = ['a', 'b']
folders = []
for path in os.listdir(root_path):
   folders.append(os.path.join(root_path, path))

for f in folders:
    os.chdir(f)
    for sub_folder in sub_folders:
        os.mkdir(sub_folder)
```

**Update:** the code below doesn't create subfolders `a` and `b`:

```
sub_folders = ['a', 'b']
folders = []

for path in os.listdir(root_path):
    if path in ('sub1', 'sub2'):
        folders.append(os.path.join(root_path, path))

for f in folders:
    os.chdir(f)
    for sub_folder in sub_folders:
        os.mkdir(sub_folder)
```

**UPDATE:** the code below works, thanks to @Baltschun Ali.

```
import os

path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/test1'
def create_sub_folder (*arg):
    if len(arg) < 3:
        for i in arg[0]:
            for j in arg[1]:
                path = i+"/"+j
                if os.path.exists(path) is False:
                    os.makedirs(path)
    else:      
        arg1 = [i+"/"+j for i in arg[0] for j in arg[1]]
        create_sub_folder(arg1,*(i for i in arg[2:]))

for dir in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, dir)):
        print(dir)
        create_sub_folder([dir], ['sub1', 'sub2'],['a','b'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more dynamic.

**EDITED CODE**

```
def create_sub_folder (*arg):
    if len(arg) < 3:
        for i in arg[0]:
            for j in arg[1]:
                path = i+"/"+j
                if os.path.exists(path) is False:
                    os.makedirs(path)
    else:      
        arg1 = [i+"/"+j for i in arg[0] for j in arg[1]]
        create_sub_folder(arg1,*(i for i in arg[2:]))
```

**CALL METHOD**

```
create_sub_folder(['A','B'],['sub1','sub2'],['a','b'])
```

**RESULT :**

before

[image]

after

[image]

you can pass more than 3 levels of subfolder
just pass more array in arg

```
create_sub_folder([],[],[],[],[],[],['a','b'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry maybe I was not clear, in fact I already have a folder structure (not need to create `"D:\test"` but your code is useful to create test data), I just want to create subfolders `a`, `b` under `sub1` and `sub2`, not sub1--a, sub1--b, or sub2--a, sub2--b.

Comment: sorry, i miss your first question (before you edit it)

Comment: Thanks, is there a method to avoid to list `['A','B']`, because I have handreds of folders at this level in real data?

Comment: do you mean, add a subfolder to all parent folder?

just get all your parent folder using `glob` and pass it into first array of arg `create_sub_folder(array_folder_from_glob,['sub1','sub2'],['a','b'])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `if` statement in the first `for` loop to avoid adding the path to the list only if it is one of `sub1` and `sub2`:

```
for path in os.listdir(root_path):
   if path in ('sub1', 'sub2'):
       folders.append(os.path.join(root_path, path))
```

Comment: Thanks, I replace your code but it doesn't work out. Please check update of my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `glob` library:

```
import glob, os

for new_dir_name in ('a','b'):
    for subn in ('sub1', 'sub2'):
        for sub_folder in glob.glob(os.path.join('*',subn), recursive=True):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(sub_folder, new_dir_name))
```

Tested in Linux:

```
$ mkdir -p {A,B}/sub1 {A,B,C}/sub2 
$ python make_sub_dirs.py # run the python script above
$ ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

Results:

```
   |-A
   |---sub1
   |-----a
   |-----b
   |---sub2
   |-----a
   |-----b
   |-B
   |---sub1
   |-----a
   |-----b
   |---sub2
   |-----a
   |-----b
   |-C
   |---sub2
   |-----a
   |-----b
   |-ipp2
   |---log
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I hope to create `a` and `b` for both `sub1` and `sub2`.

Comment: Sorry that I miss this point. Will correct the answer in a moment.

Comment: I think maybe we should use `os.walk`, no?

Comment: @ahbon That will also work. But `glob` has the nice feature of "wildcard" expansion so that we don't need to handle the path-pattern matching in our code.

Comment: I try with your method, it didn't create `a` and `b`, did you make folders successfully?